# Small BFS Detail Clarification

Tags: algorithm, optimization, breadth-first-search

The standard bfs implementation is something like (courtesy of Wikipedia):

```
 Breadth-First-Search(Graph, root):
    create empty set S
    create empty queue Q      
    root.parent = NIL
    Q.enqueue(root)                      
    while Q is not empty:
        current = Q.dequeue()
        if current is the goal
            return current
        for each node n that is adjacent to current:
            if n is not in S:
                add n to S
                n.parent = current
                Q.enqueue(n)
```

I was wondering why the check to see if current is the goal can not be done while looking through the neighbors adjacent to current. For ex. something like:

```
 Breadth-First-Search(Graph, root):
    create empty set S
    create empty queue Q      
    root.parent = NIL
    if root is the goal
        return root
    Q.enqueue(root)                      
    while Q is not empty:
        current = Q.dequeue()
        for each node n that is adjacent to current:
            if n is the goal          // check here instead
                  n.parent = current
                  return n
            if n is not in S:
                add n to S
                n.parent = current
                Q.enqueue(n)
```

The idea is that you would catch the word as soon as it is found in a neighbor. You can ensure this is the shortest path because there is no way a path in the queue already contains a path since we would have caught that case before it happened too.

I understand this introduces the need to add an extra check before the while loop to see if root is the goal but other than that, is there some reason bfs is not implemented like this? It should technically be faster right?

Answer (score 1):

Your version works fine if you put in the check for the root (you should put that in the question).

In some situations your way will be faster, and in some situations it will be slower.  It can be slower, for example, if there is some kind of penalty (like an extra cache miss) for accessing the contents of each node twice.

Usually the difference is not significant and folks do it the first way just because the code is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd refactor it even further.  I noticed that root was not directly added to S which means that it would get added later and then checked again. I moved the creation of S and Q til after the early root return. Switched the while which means that root doesn't have to be enqueued to Q then have Q checked to see if root is in it then dequeue root. I moved the in S check to be first inside the for each loop because that check will prevent the goal check one or more times each loop, the goal check would only prevent the in S check once total. It also let me remove the n.parent = current code line duplication, doesn't help performance but I don't like duplication.

```
 Breadth-First-Search(Graph, root):
    root.parent = NIL
    if root is the goal
        return root
    create empty set S
    add root to S
    create empty queue Q
    current = root
    while true
        for each node n that is adjacent to current:
            if n in S:
                continue
            n.parent = current
            if n is the goal
                return n
            add n to S
            Q.enqueue(n)
        if Q empty
            break
        current = Q.dequeue()
```